# How to sign transaction and return txn hash in flutter with injected_web3

Tags: flutter

```
 Future<String> signTransaction(
      InAppWebViewController _, JsTransactionObject data, int chainId) async {
    return "0x45fb0060681bf5d8ea675ab0b3f76aa15c84b172f2fb3191b7a8ceb1e6a7f372";
  }
```

this is the code to sign. how to sign and return the hash? I am using flutter_injected_web3 library.